# Fengyuanchen Cropperjs Crop Ellipse shape?

Tags: javascript, canvas

When cropping a circle, I tried setting  `cropper.setAspectRatio(0);` which lets me free drag to get ellipse shapes, but when it crops, I end up with a round crop, but with transparent edges that fill the extra missing info. This image was supposed to be `width=722px height=182px`
[image: vaohv]

Here is the function to get round canvas which works for perfectly round circles, but not ellipses:

```
function getRoundedCanvas(sourceCanvas) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var width = sourceCanvas.width;
  var height = sourceCanvas.height;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  context.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
  context.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, width, height);
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(width / 2, height / 2, Math.min(width, height) / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  context.fill();
  return canvas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify it a bit to work:

```
function getRoundedCanvas(sourceCanvas) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  offsetTop = Math.round(cropper.getCropBoxData().top);
  offsetLeft = Math.round(cropper.getCropBoxData().left);  
  var width = sourceCanvas.width;
  var height = sourceCanvas.height;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  context.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
  context.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, width, height);
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  context.beginPath();
  context.ellipse(width/2, height/2, width/2, height/2, 0 * Math.PI, 0, 45 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
  return canvas;
}
```